# I want to display my safari downloads in the notification centre

Tags: macos, applescript, notificationcenter

I'm fairly comfortable using applescript, however I know that there is no way to display anything in the notification centre using applescript.

What I want to do is to be able to have a loading bar in the notification centre for things I am downloading and then to give a notification once the item has downloaded. I also want to make it so that if you are to click on the item in the notification centre it will take you to the item that has been downloaded.

Comment: Have a look at this hint on MacOSXHints http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20120831112030251

Comment: @markhunte I don't think the problem will be putting something in the notification centre so much as having an Applescript get called when the download is finished